# Pressure / force: surface vs volume

Tags: forces, pressure, measurements, volume

I recently read about measuring the expansion of wood when wet. The set-up (A) was a 1" cube of wood, in water, with a load sensor above, which reported ~100 lb/in^2 (I think they meant psi). I assume if I placed another cube right next to it (B), the total force would roughly double to 200 lb. What happens if I place a cube on top of a cube? (C) The surface is 1 in^2, but there's twice as much volume behind it compared to (A). Does this extra volume matter? Is the total force 200 lb now?
[image: Illustration]

Comment: To keep the wood at its original height requires a stress of 100 psi. The area that's loaded is 1 square inch in A and 2 square inches in B, producing the corresponding forces from the product of stress × area. This enables one to predict the force in C.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own "plain English" reasoning, not sure if it's correct. The expanding wood can be thought of as an outward force acting in all directions. Since it's a cube (6 sides), each side receives 1/6 of this outward force. In case A), 2 sides out of 6 are communicating with our measuring system (the bottom of the container and the load sensor), so we capture only their portions of the total force. The cube, as a whole, produces 300 lbs of outward force. We engage 2 out of its 6 sides with our measuring system, so we capture 1/3 of the total: 100 lbs. The remainder dissipates into the water through the other sides. In B) we have two cubes, each produces 300 lbs of force for a total of 600 lbs. In B) 4 sides (2 top, 2 bottom) out of 12 engage our measuring system (the bottom and the sensor) so we measure (or "capture") 4/12 = 1/3 of the total 600 lbs: 200 lbs. In C) only 2 sides interface with our measuring system: the top and the bottom. The 8 vertical sides dissipate their portion of the force into the water. The two sides in the middle, where the two cubes meet, exchange forces internally, they don't communicate with our measuring system, so they don't contribute. So, in C), out of the total 600 lbs we capture 2/12 = 1/6 = 100 lbs, i.e. we're back to case A).

Comment: I agree with everything except the 6-sides stuff, 1/6th force, and 300 lbs total. It's not useful or correct to add magnitudes of forces in different directions. You can perform the same analysis and obtain the same (correct) result by noting that a vertical load of 100 lbs is required to keep one box at its original height.